# Opening a file in a tab

Tags: c#, tabs

I'm still learning, but I'd like to open a file in a new tab with the name of the file in the tab name. I can only open a file when I have a tab open already. Here is what I have at the moment.

```
private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Stream myStream;
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            if ((myStream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
            {
                string strfilename = openFileDialog1.FileName;
                string filetext = File.ReadAllText(strfilename);
                GetActiveEditor().Text = filetext;
            }
        }
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Also, if you have any tips on saving a file in a selected tab, that'd be great.

Comment: you'll have to add a tabpage in your tab control everytime you are opening a file. Also note here, that you can't add the same Edtor control in all tab pages. Either shift your editor to active tab page or add individual editor to every tab page.

Comment: what the errors/bad behavior you are getting/